# Lightweight entities and instances

Tags: codefluent

We would like to insert some data in our generated model using instances. However we have entities containing light weight entities as in:

```
<cf:entity name="O" namespace="{0}.AOA">
    [...]
    <cf:property name="B" typeName="BO">
       [...]
```

where the type BO is defined as lightweight entity:

```
<cf:entity name="BO" namespace="{0}.AOA" lightweight="true">    
    <cf:property name="IdentificatiecodeOR" typeName="AN16">      
    </cf:property>    
    [...]
```

How should the instance for the entity O be defined to input data in the identificatiecodeOR property?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample that uses a Contact entity and a lightweight Address entity. It was created using the Visual Modeler component of Codefluent Entities. Are you not using the Visual Modeler?

```
<cf:entity name="Contact" namespace="Demo1" categoryPath="/Demo1">
<cf:property name="Id" key="true" />
<cf:property name="FirstName" />
<cf:property name="LastName" />
<cf:property name="Address" typeName="{0}.Address" />
<cf:instance>
  <cf:instanceValue name="Id">b6ec9c67-755d-42d8-ae7c-0ac3cab8db1f</cf:instanceValue>
  <cf:instanceValue name="FirstName">Jon</cf:instanceValue>
  <cf:instanceValue name="LastName">Smith</cf:instanceValue>
  <cf:instanceValue name="Address" preserveEscaping="true"><City>San Jose</City><Line1>100 Main St</Line1><Line2>Bld 5</Line2><PostalCode>99999</PostalCode><State>FL</State></cf:instanceValue>
</cf:instance>
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample, will try it. We are not using the visual modeler.